# API post not visible in FB Mobile App?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When a link is posted with the PHP SDK to /me/feed the post isn't visible in the 
Facebook App for iPhone but shows up anywhere else like desktops facebook.com and even on mobile via Safari m.facebook.com

All permissions are fine, the used access token is valid, Mobile Site URL is set, etc.

What else could be wrong ?

Comment: Where does the link point to?

Comment: The link in the post points to a dynamically generated page on the same domain specified in the Mobile Site URL